# MvvmCross initial IMvxViewModel ViewAppeared not being called when in an MvxTabbbedPage on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

We have an `MvxTabbedPage` and child `MvxContentPage`s in our Xamarin.Forms project.

On Android, I'm finding that the `ViewAppeared` override on my first child page is not being called the first time the `MvxTabbedPage` is being shown.

When switching tabs, it subsequently is being called correctly.

I'm initialising the PageModels in the `ViewAppearing` for the `MvxTabbedPage`'s PageModel as below:

```
public override async void ViewAppearing()
{
    await ShowInitialViewModels();
    base.ViewAppearing();
}

private bool viewModelsInitialised = false;
private async Task ShowInitialViewModels()
{
    if (!viewModelsInitialised)
    {
        await _BusyManager.SetBusy();
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        tasks.Add(_MvxNavigationService.Navigate<HomePageModel>());
        tasks.Add(_MvxNavigationService.Navigate<MyBenefitsPageModel>());
        tasks.Add(_MvxNavigationService.Navigate<ClaimsPageModel>());
        tasks.Add(_MvxNavigationService.Navigate<ContactUsPageModel>());
        tasks.Add(_MvxNavigationService.Navigate<SettingsPageModel>());
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        viewModelsInitialised = true;
        await _BusyManager.SetUnBusy();
    }
}
```

Have others seen this behaviour, and/or should I be doing something differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's this Forms bug:

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3855

which is referenced by this MvvmCross issue

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/2823

(thanks to Pedro for pointing me in this direction on Slack:)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Playground project](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/Projects/Playground) of mvvmcross. You should manage your tabs initializations separately in a viewmodel and the XF view code behind.

```
public class YourTabsViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    public YourTabsViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;

        ShowInitialViewModelsCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(ShowInitialViewModels);
    }

    public IMvxAsyncCommand ShowInitialViewModelsCommand { get; private set; }

    private async Task ShowInitialViewModels()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>
        {
            tasks.Add(_navigationService.Navigate<HomePageModel>();
            tasks.Add(_navigationService.Navigate<MyBenefitsPageModel>());
            tasks.Add(_navigationService.Navigate<ClaimsPageModel>());
            tasks.Add(_navigationService.Navigate<ContactUsPageModel>());
            tasks.Add(_navigationService.Navigate<SettingsPageModel>());
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

And then on the code behind of your XF view

```
[MvxTabbedPagePresentation(TabbedPosition.Root, NoHistory = true)]
public partial class YourTabsPage : MvxTabbedPage<YourTabsViewModel>
{
    public YourTabsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool _firstTime = true;

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (_firstTime)
        {
            ViewModel.ShowInitialViewModelsCommand.ExecuteAsync(null);

            _firstTime = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as I'm already doing? The code I posted above is from the ViewModel.

The behaviour I'm seeing is described by the bug I've referenced above.